# Android app doesnt work without wifi connection

Tags: java, android

I have one small android app which insert data to table using MySQL (via php site). Everything works fine when I'm using wifi but when I disable wifi data is not stored in database. Here is my code which I use to connect to my local php file:

```
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.2:6969/android/index.php";

        try {
            URL address = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) address.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("emailAddress", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String line;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I discovered that the problem is with line:

```
OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
```

My app stops there.

Is there a way to force this application to work without wifi connection?

Here is logcat when I start my app on debug usb mode on my android phone:

```
E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk netid=0; mark=0
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo( app_uid:10226
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo() uid prop:
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo() getuid():10226
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk netid=0; mark=0
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo( app_uid:10226
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo() uid prop:
 D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo() getuid():10226
 D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: mtk ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
```

Comment: refer http://androidcss.com/android/test-android-app-php-localhost-wamp/

Comment: can you share the logcat

Comment: @shubhamgoyal I added logcat for my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a library that handles everything for you.

Like
http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Here is an example code how it works for URL-Encoded Requests:

```
 RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("name", "name")
            .add("emailAdress", "xxx@xxx.com")
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
```

And a more important thing is. You are having a 192.168.x.x IP-Address. This is used for a private network and is **not** available through public Internet. If you know your Routers public IP you could make a forwarding to your PC, but i would not suggest that to you.

Comment: "You are having a 192.168.x.x IP-Address." Of course... I should kill myself now.

Comment: And thanks for this useful library! I used my local address only for testing, now I put the proper url which is public of course and I hope it will work :)